# GitHub Pages stopped updating one markdown file

Tags: markdown, github-pages, github-flavored-markdown

I've been putting up and updating a set of linked markdown files on GitHub Pages successfully for awhile, however it broke recently and stopped updating just one particular markdown file.  All the other files still update correctly.  The page not being updated is also not displaying correctly.

I can see the file being updated on GitHub (outside of GitHub Pages) and it displays correctly there.

Any ideas as to why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**: Look for and delete html versions of markdown files from repository.

E.g.:

```
$ ls docs/css_notes
docs/css_notes/css_crib_notes.md
docs/css_notes/css_crib_notes.html
$ git rm docs/css_notes/css_crib_notes.html
$ git commit -m "Removed html exported version of markdown file"
```

**Explanation**:
It turns out I had accidentally added to the repository an html exported version of the markdown file, which GitHub Pages was displaying instead of it generating from the updated markdown file.